# Excel formula to get value from another sheet (Same workbook)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Table - 1**

| Course A (Excel column B) | Category (Excel column C) |
| --- | --- |
| Adobe Premier for Beginners | Adobe |
| Advanced InDesign Training | Adobe |
| After Effects Pro Course | Adobe |
| Enterprise Networking | CISCO |
| Excel Advanced | Microsoft |
| Network Design | CISCO |

**Table - 2**

| Keyword (Excel column G) | Category (Excel column H) |
| --- | --- |
| Effects | Adobe |
| Excel | Microsoft |
| InDesign | Adobe |
| Network | CISCO |
| Photoshop | Adobe |
| Adobe | Adobe |

I have two tables in Excel. Table -1 and Table - 2.

I am trying to assign category to table -1 (Column C). For which I am using Table-2.

**Assumptions**: Both the tables are in the same excel and same sheet (Refer table header for column ID)

I am able to successfully assign it with the following formula

`=INDEX($H$3:$H$9,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$3:$G$9,B3)),0))`

This formular finds the particular keyword from table-2 against table-1's column 1. Then returns the value on table-1's column 2.

`=INDEX($H$3:$H$9,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$3:$G$9,B3)),0))`

it works as expected. I want to move the table-2 to different sheet in the same Workbook. I tried changing the formula by prefixing the sheet name before the columnID and tested it unsuccessfully.

Comment: What was the formula try that did not succeed? (In case the sheet name contains a space wrap it in `'` like: `'Sheet 2'!$G$3:$G$9`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not providing the worksheet name and the Range you moved your Table 2 to, but if I was to assume you moved the table 2 to Column A & B of Sheet2, then the following would work as expected:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$7,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$7,B2)),0))
```

As per comments, if the worksheet name has a space within the name itself, then the following would work:

```
=INDEX('Sheet 2'!$B$2:$B$7,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Sheet 2'!$A$2:$A$7,B2)),0))
```

Comment: you are spot on. .I missed the space :) It worked now.
thank you!